# Interrupted time series using GLMM / GAMM: which time variables should be smoothed?

Tags: time-series, glmm, generalized-additive-model, segmented-regression

I have conducted a controlled interrupted time series analysis within a GLMM framework. I have run the analysis in both the control and treatment groups separately to quantify the basic effects:

```
# Treatment group
its.trt <- glmmTMB(out ~ ar1(time + 0 | id) + post + time_post + (1 | id) + offset(log(exposure)),
                   data = df,
                   family = poisson)

# Control group
its.tau <- glmmTMB(out ~ ar1(time + 0 | id) + post + time_post + (1 | id) + offset(log(exposure)),
                   data = df,
                   weights = wts,
                   family = poisson)
```

I have also run the analysis in both groups to determine whether differences exist between the two groups:

```
# Controlled ITS
cits <- glmmTMB(out ~ ar1(time + 0 | id) + post + time_post + group + time_group + post_group + time_post_group + (1 | id) + offset(log(exposure)),
                data = df,
                weights = wts,
                family = poisson)
```

I would now like to run the analysis within a GAMM framework.

**Question 1:** To do so, which variables should be smoothed? Is it simply the time variable:

```
# Treatment group
its.trt <- bam(out ~ s(time) + post + time_post + s(id, bs = "re") + offset(log(exposure)),
               data = df,
               family = poisson)

# Control group
its.tau <- bam(out ~ s(time) + post + time_post + s(id, bs = "re") + offset(log(exposure)),
               data = df,
               weights = wts,
               family = poisson)

# Controlled ITS
cits <- bam(out ~ s(time) + post + time_post + group + time_group + post_group + time_post_group + s(id, bs = "re") + offset(log(exposure)),
            data = df,
            weights = wts,
            family = poisson)
```

?

Or the time variable and all its composites:

```
# Treatment group
its.trt <- bam(out ~ s(time) + post + s(time_post) + s(id, bs = "re") + offset(log(exposure)),
               data = df,
               family = poisson)

# Control group
its.tau <- bam(out ~ s(time) + post + s(time_post) + s(id, bs = "re") + offset(log(exposure)),
               data = df,
               weights = wts,
               family = poisson)

# Controlled ITS
cits <- bam(out ~ s(time) + post + s(time_post) + group + s(time_group) + post_group + s(time_post_group) + s(id, bs = "re") + offset(log(exposure)),
            data = df,
            weights = wts,
            family = poisson)
```

?

**Question 2:** Assuming autocorrelation is present in the residuals, is it better to smooth the term(s), use an alternative correlation structure (e.g., through `gamm`), or both?

Any assistance would be appreciated. Clarification of the `R` code (inc., variations as required) would be greatly appreciated.